# Read from a string until specific char in Android

Tags: java, android, string, char

How can I read numbers from a string until I find a specific char, in my case - a dot.

For example I have a

```
String date = "18.8.2011"
int mDay = 0;
int mMonth = 0;
int mYear = 0;
```

And I want to make `mDay = 18`, `mMonth = 8` and `mYear = 2011` - I want to be able to copy the digits until I find a dot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **split** method of String class.

```
String []ar=date.split("[.]");
int mDay=Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
..
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] arr = date.split("[.]");

int mDay = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int mMonth = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
int myear = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
```

Comment: Please edit your post and change the method name. It must be **split()**.

Comment: @jon @ntc Thanks for the answers, but I receive a 
`Error caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the `int mDay = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);` line. Do you know what what's causing this?

Comment: @ntc Yes it is - `08-18 16:00:44.694: ERROR/log_tag(1321): date: 18.8.2011`

Comment: @Stefan Doychev - split() method uses regular expression pattern so the use char "[.]" instead of ".". The "." is predefined character class and it represent "Any character (may or may not match)".